# Npm version bringing back double string key:value pair

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, version, npm-version

Running npm version brings back a really weird key-value pair. I don't even know what to search to find out how to remove this.

'livelocation-master': '1.0.0'

Background: I tried using react-native when I was first playing around with code, I probably added this on accident.

OS: Windows 10

Skill level: Fresh out of a 3-month coding Bootcamp

Here's the complete object returned from npm version:

$ npm version
{

'livelocation-master': '1.0.0',

npm: '6.14.5',

ares: '1.16.0',

brotli: '1.0.7',

cldr: '37.0',

http_parser: '2.9.3',
icu: '67.1',

llhttp: '2.0.4',

modules: '72',

napi: '6',

nghttp2: '1.40.0',

node: '12.17.0',

openssl: '1.1.1g',

tz: '2019c',

unicode: '13.0',

uv: '1.37.0',

v8: '7.8.279.23-node.37',

zlib: '1.2.11'
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days of digging, I discovered a mysterious node_modules folder at the /users/ level. This was also causing issues with create-react-app due to having an old eslint version installed up there! I deleted the folder and it fixed the issues with create-react-app and npm version does not return that double string key:value pair.